# Manual Testing/Automation - Selenium webdriver/TestNG/Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am still new to automation, I've created a few tests using webdriver and TestNG - Data driven passing in parameters from Excel etc.

I am in a manual position so mostly doing manual Test Plans etc.I am Self taught selenium, webdriver etc. I am still basic using Java and just starting to understand everything. I've managed to create tests filling out forms on webpages and checking if they were submitted etc. How much more advanced do the UI automation tests get? Also what else do automation testers test apart from web/software screens?

Also I want to move into automation full time as I cant see a long serving career in manual test plans, Would I be out of my depth instantly joining an automation team with only being self taught and only having basic java language skills?

I use selenium Webdriver + java bindings + TestNG framework with data driven approach, If I was to use nightwatch.js and script my tests in java-script would I have much difficulty converting from java to java-script?

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Selenium *and* Java, things might get a little difficult. But it's worth the effort IMHO, especially when your test cases are very time-consuming and don't require much intelligence from the person (or program) that execute them. When running my Selenium test cases in Google Chrome, which is the best choice in terms of execution speed and stability, no matter what platform, we usually save between 85 and 90 % of execution time compared to clicking the test cases manually. Plus, we can execute them as often as we want without any manual (or financial) effort.

You might consider watching the free YouTube video tutorials by "executeautomation", which deal with Selenium in Java, page object model, TestNG and related stuff, without assuming too much previous knowledge. I watched them all, and they helped me very much when I started using Selenium.

Comment: Thanks,

I am the only tester in my dev team and am at the point now were I am unsure how to improve my automation skills as there are no other testers on my team to help educate to a more advanced level. I will 100% check those videos out. Thanks.

Comment: I am the only tester in my dev team, too. Once you've seen the videos, you can also find a lot of input and assistance here at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

I recommend these:

1. Page Objects pattern.
2. Use GIT or any other source code version control.
3. Design workflow or framework for your automation tests. The workflow start from developers (who implement test scripts) sit at their desk, open IDE, get dependencies, implement test scripts, deploy tests, execute tests, review test results, fix test scripts.

From my experience, the most important part are 1. how to maintain test scripts and 2. how to persuade the developers to help us to develop and maintain test scripts, and monitor test results.

My technique to persuade developers is broadcasting failed tests to managers or showing test results in public areas.

Answer (score 0):

I was too fairly new to automation but automation using nightwatch.js is very easy. First thing is you dont require any framework. Just need one configuration file to mention where your tests and page objects will be. webdriver and chromedriver or explorer driver path and you are set to write tests. Writing tests in nightwatch.js requires a fair-bit knowledge of node.js but the syntax used for writing tests are simple. Withing hours I had my first test automated and up and running. just follow nightwatchjs.org, it contains all the syntaxes you need to build your test.

Cheers,
Amit